# tf command for retrieving a list pending changesets

Tags: tfs, changeset

Given a changeset number say C12345, how does one get a list of all changesets that have followed after C12345 that may or may not have been pulled down from the TFS server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using TFS TF History to determine the latest changeset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338149/using-tfs-tf-history-to-determine-the-latest-changeset)

Comment: Oh interesting. I tried searching for just that. It did not come up. I think this is thread more succinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the root, call:

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /V:C#####~T
```

Note: C12345 will be included at the tail of the list.

So in your case it would be:

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /V:C12345~T
```