# How to get current changeset number in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using Visual studio 2012?

I can't find current changeset number of my solution in team foundation server.

How to know which version of code is running in my solution?

Comment: I don't think it's something you can readily do given the fact each file / folder can be on a different version and that each file is only given a new version when you change it. TBH it's not something I have needed to do in 2 years working in TFS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using TFS TF History to determine the latest changeset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338149/using-tfs-tf-history-to-determine-the-latest-changeset)

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer, right click on the root node for your solution, then select View History.

[image: view history]

the latest changeset will be shown on the right

[image: history]

Comment: The question is not about how to get a specific revision.  Its about how to know the revision number that he is currently working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W
```

abbreviated version:
    `tf hist . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /v:w`

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace/